# How to solve the inequality $2^x\ge a+bx$?

Tags: calculus, inequality

Let $a$ and $b$ be real constants where $b$ is positive. What is the small real number $x_0>0$ such that
$$2^x \ge a+bx?$$

Here is what I have tried. Suppose $a=0$. Fix a positive integer $n$. Then $2^x=e^{(\log 2)x}=\left(e^{\frac{\log 2}{n}x}\right)^n\ge \left(1+\frac{\log 2}{n}x\right)^n\gt\left(\frac{\log 2}{n}x\right)^n$. The inequality $\left(\frac{\log 2}{n}x\right)^n\ge bx$ is solved as $x\ge \left[\frac{b}{(\frac{\log 2}{n})^n}\right]^{1/(n-1)}=\frac{b^{1/(n-1)}}{(\log 2)^{n/(n-1)}} n^{n/(n-1)}$. Therefore 
$$x_0\ge \inf_n \frac{b^{1/(n-1)}}{(\log 2)^{n/(n-1)}} n^{n/(n-1)}.$$
Can one do better than this or simplify this expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're talking about a [transcendental equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation), so that the solutions (if any) can be determined only if the parameters $a, b$ take particular values - that is, when the equation is a "nice" one and leads to some "trick" for expressing its roots in terms of elementary functions. Other than that, you can only use numerical methods to find arbitrary-precision approximations.

**Addendum**: of course, the answer using Lambert's W function, although simplifying matters, does not change anything at all: just define the $\diamond$-function to be

$\diamond(a) := F^{-1}(a)$, where $F(t) = 2^t - t$,

and have fun writing a $\mathtt{Mathematica}$ package. Not offending anyone, the point of this is that the solution to $2^x = a + bx$ is not expressible through *elementary* functions, since the OP seemed to be wanting an explicit $x_0$.

Answer (score 2):

We can write, for $b\gt0$,
$$
\begin{align}
e^{x\log2} &\geq a+bx\\
-\frac{1}{b}(\log2)e^{x\log2}&\leq -\frac{a}{b}\log2-x\log2\\
-\frac{1}{b}(\log2)e^{-\frac{a}{b}\log2}e^{\frac{a}{b}\log2+x\log2}&\leq -\frac{a}{b}\log2-x\log2
\end{align}
$$
Set 
$$
w=-\frac{a}{b}\log2-x\log2\\
z_0=-\frac{1}{b}(\log2)e^{-\frac{a}{b}\log2}
$$ 
so that we can write
$$we^w\geq z_0$$
This can be solved using [Lambert $W$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_Function), defined as the inverse function of $we^w$. This inverse is not unique. Usually the inverse in $[-1,+\infty)$ is called the principal branch and indicated $W_0$. The inverse in $(-\infty,-1]$ is indicated $W_{-1}$.

If $z_0\leq-1/e$ then all $w$ (and so all $x$) are solutions.

If $z_0>-1/e$ then the solutions are
$$
w\leq W_{-1}(z_0)\qquad\text{or}\qquad w\geq W_0(z_0)
$$
These values can be easily evaluated numerically, for example in Mathematica $W_0$ is `ProductLog[z]` and $W_{-1}$ is `ProductLog[-1,z]`. The endpoints of the intervals could be easily written in terms of $x$, given the linear relation between $w$ and $x$.

Answer (score 0):

First note that such $x_0$ can not exists. In fact, $2^x > -1+x, \  \forall x$.Note too that $2^x$ is convex. In fact,$(2^x)´´=(e^{x\ln 2})´´=´(\ln 2)^{2}e^{x\ln 2}\ge0$. Then if there exist $x>0$ such that $a+bx\ge 2^x$ the small $x_0$ such that $2^x\ge a+bx$ will be the small root of the equation $2^x=a+bx$.

Comment: You write $2^{x}=e^{2\ln x}$ but it should be $e^{x \ln 2}$